# Plateauing derivative of smooth function

Tags: derivatives

Does there exist a smooth, non-piecewise, non-linear and differentiable function whose derivative equals $a$ for multiple consecutive values of the independent variable? In other words, what 'natural' function (i.e., containing no absolute values, rounding, etc.) can a take the derivative of and part of the derivative look like a horizontal line when graphed, even if over just two abscissae?

Comment: Is the derivative allowed to be piecewise? If so consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = \exp(-\frac 1x)$ for $x>0$, $0$ otherwise.  Note $f \in C^{\infty}$. Then $g(x) = \int_0^x f$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: A non-linear analytic function cannot satisfy the conditions, I'm pretty sure, so I doubt there's anything more natural.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 that's what I figured too

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question properly, one example is $f(x) = sin(x)$. The derivative is $f'(x) = cos(x)$. Say $a = f'(x_0)$, then for $x_k = x_0 + 2k\pi$, the derivative is also $a$, i.e. $f'(x_k) = f'(x_0) = a$.